# How to exclude some nodes

Tags: java, neo4j, dijkstra

Is there any ways to exclude some certain nodes from Neo4j Dijkstra algorithm based on  property?

I know, I can set allowed relatinoships and directions in method *forTypeAndDirection*, but this doesn't help me in my case.

Let's assume I have following code:

```
try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {

    Node startNode = graphDb.getNodeById(12353);
    Node endNode = graphDb.getNodeById(12356);

    CostEvaluator<Double> costEvaluator = new CostEvaluator<Double>() {
        @Override
        public Double getCost(Relationship relationship, Direction direction) {
        Integer cost = Integer.parseInt(relationship.getProperty("cost").toString());               
            return cost.doubleValue();
        }
    };      

    PathFinder<WeightedPath> finder = GraphAlgoFactory.dijkstra(
        PathExpanders.forTypeAndDirection( RelationshipTypes.RELATED, Direction.OUTGOING), costEvaluator );

        WeightedPath path = finder.findSinglePath( startNode, endNode );        
        System.out.println(path.length());
        tx.success();
    }
}
```

When Dijkstra goes through node with property name:'London' how to stop executing this path and continue somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently ran into a similar problem where I needed custom `PathExpander` to perform some traversal. I did something like this (I modified my original code a bit to fit your case, but it still could be buggy, so look carefully):

```
final private static class FilteringExpander implements PathExpander {
    private final Direction direction;

    private FilteringExpander(final Direction direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public FilteringExpander() {
        this.direction = Direction.OUTGOING;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Relationship> expand(Path neoPath, BranchState state) {
        if (!neoPath.endNode().getProperty("name").equals("London")) {
            return neoPath.endNode().getRelationships(RelationshipTypes.RELATED, direction);
        } else {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PathExpander reverse() {
        return new FilteringExpander(direction.reverse());
    }
}
```

Hope it's clear enough. If you'll have any questions, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Thank you, one problem. I've got error on the variable path in the second override, I am not sure how it works. This my code: http://pastebin.com/wjShzxxA.

Comment: @EdWood, that's my fault, I just copy-pasted the code without paying an appropriate amount of attention to the process. Fixed it now, try again.

Comment: @EdWood, of course nothing happens! You also have to USE the expander instead the one that you are already using (as an argument to `dijkstra`). You can't expect anything from the mere class definition - you should also instantiate it and use somewhere as well ;)